# Reducing coefficients of matrix elements in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix, sympy

I would like to remove or minimize to 1 any numbers of matrix elements that are not exponents.  I want this to be done within symbolic calculations (sympy module).

```
from sympy import*
init_printing()

X = symbols('X')
A = Matrix([[1, 2*X**2], [4*X, 2]])
A
```

[image]

I did try to fix this with `subs()` function but then it also affects the exponents, which I want to keep as they are.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
from sympy import*
init_printing()

X = symbols('X')
A = Matrix([[1, -2*X**2], [4*X, -2]])

for i in range(len(A)):
    if  A[i].is_Number:
        A[i] = A[i] / abs(A[i])
    else:
        A[i] = A[i].primitive()[1]
A
```

*Edit: allow for negatives

Comment: Actually the problem occurs if one of the numbers is negative as it doesn't transfer its sign... How could that be fixed with using symbols?